# Debugging an NPM module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Currently, I've created an NPM module and published it to NPM and included it in a separate project for use. I've performed NPM link so I don't have to publish every time I make a change and those updates are being reflected appropriately. However, I can't seem to debug the module itself. I've tried placing a debugger in the modules code within the node_modules directory and I've tried to place one in the actual module project, but to no avail. Is there a best practice for debugging an NPM module? If it helps, I'm using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: It may have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341088/how-can-i-debug-node-modules)

Comment: Thank you, @vahdet. It's close, but ideally I'd like to use something more interactive, but I do appreciate the response.

Comment: Hi @tim I know its almost 2.5 years, but did you get to know, how to debug or place breakpoints in  after doing a npm link to a npm library (or module) ?

Comment: I unfortunately did not, I just use npm link...