# How to easily test an npm module as I code?

Tags: javascript, npm, read-eval-print-loop

I am working on modifying [@editorjs/nested-list](https://github.com/editor-js/nested-list).  I want a way to do very quick testing as I go, without a lot of install.  I put together a little web page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/editorjs@latest"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>EditorJS</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="editorjs"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
    <script>
const editor = new EditorJS({
    holder: 'editorjs',
 }
);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

with `index.js` being the source for nested-list.

I get an error message:

> Access to script at 'file:///.../nested-list/src/index.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

What is the easiest way for me to test my mods to index.js as I go?

Can I modify this HTML somehow, or do I need a different toolchain?

P.S. I see [this unanswered possibly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49453499/debugging-an-npm-module).

P.P.S.  [This is also related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888576/how-to-develop-npm-module-locally), but they assume there is an app ("MyApp"), whereas I have no app.  Maybe I need to set up a dummy app?  That's a bit annoying.

Comment: have you considered using webpack dev server?

Comment: I just looked up the webpack dev server, thanks. I see https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/. But, it's also a matter of setting up the scaffolding for this particular node module that actually works. I seem to get stuck in pit after pit.

Comment: As an example, after I use the http-server referenced below, and I run `npm run build:dev` in the `nested-list` package, I can't seem to import the NestedList symbol in any one of 10 variations. So it's really a working setup with code + tools + scaffolding for testing this code as I go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple development server to quickly run your html files in the localhost by avoiding all `file://` security complications.

My favourite is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Very simple steps:

1. ```
   npm install --global http-server
   ```
2. Go to the directory where you have the index.html file and enter the command `http-server`

The index.html file is now available at http://localhost:8080

Comment: Oh sweet, thank you! That sounds like what I want.  However, when I do this, it has a bunch of other complaints about not finding files that make me wonder if the code is just not set up to be debugged this way. It gets 400 (file not found) for `utils/dom` from `import * as Dom from './utils/dom';` when there is a `utils/dom.js`.

Comment: Ah, I bet if I do `npm run build:dev` I can find the stuff to include, and it'll be fast enough.

Comment: Hmm, it's not obvious how to import the right symbols from the dist directory. I wish I had a blog post on a really simple but complete debug setup.

Comment: I decided to accept your answer, it was a piece of what I needed. Thanks. The other piece was to use their npm dev build to get the built javascript, and import it correctly.